# ¿Cómo navegar dentro del popover?

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando un plugin, el cual hace la función de Popover. Este tiene 2 formas de activarse. La primera dando click sobre el elementos sobre el cual yo quiero que el popover sea activado y la segunda pasando el puntero del mouse. En pocas palabras,"Click" y "Hover".

Mi duda está en como hacer para que cuando yo use la segunda opción(Hover), yo pueda navegar dentro del popover sin que este se cierre.

El plugin que utilizo se encuentra en este sitio web:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/tooltip/Minimal-CSS3-Animated-jQuery-Popover-Plugin.html

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('[data-role="popover2"]').popover({
     trigger: 'hover' // click | hover
     });

     });
 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="popover-wrapper">
   <a href="#" data-role="popover2" data-target="popover-target">Hover 
    here</a>
 <div class="popover-modal popover-target">
<div class="popover-body">
    <img width="400px" height="200px" src="Imagenes/high-resolution-
      wallpaper-nature-1366x768.jpg">
       </div>
         </div>
          </span>
```

Comment: ¿Existe la posibilidad de que aportes más información sobre como estás usando dicho plugin agregando un ejemplo? Lo ideal sería un __[mcve]__.

Comment: La manera más sencilla de que el popover no desaparezca cuando el mouse sale del elemento al que le haces hover es que el popover exista dentro del elemento. O sea `<elemento>texto<popover></popover></elemento>`. De esa manera al pasar el mouse al popover todavía sigues dentro del elemento padre. Tendrías que revisar como lo genera tu plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[¿Esto es lo que buscas?](http://jsfiddle.net/dLQQL/), se que es independiente a el plugin que estás utilizando, pero podría ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la respuesta sin sitios externos?, StackOverflow tiene sus propios snippets, no hace falta usar jsfiddle puesto que  los enlaces a dicho sitio se pueden perder, haciendo la respuesta inútil al despojarlo del contenido.

Comment: @Mosiah Ricardo Algo asi,pero ¿cómo agrego elementos html dentro?